# How do populate valid params in a grails test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

Kinda new here in groovy and grails. I tried to run `grails install-templates` and saw the generated test.groovy which looks like this...

```
`<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>

import org.junit.*
import grails.test.mixin.*

@TestFor(${className}Controller)
@Mock(${className})
class ${className}ControllerTests {


    def populateValidParams(params) {
      assert params != null
      // TODO: Populate valid properties like...
      //params["name"] = 'someValidName'
    }

    void testIndex() {
        controller.index()
        assert "/$propertyName/list" == response.redirectedUrl
    }

    void testList() {

        def model = controller.list()

        assert model.${propertyName}InstanceList.size() == 0
        assert model.${propertyName}InstanceTotal == 0
    }

    void testCreate() {
       def model = controller.create()

       assert model.${propertyName}Instance != null
    }

    void testSave() {
        controller.save()

        assert model.${propertyName}Instance != null
        assert view == '/${propertyName}/create'

        response.reset()

        populateValidParams(params)
        controller.save()

        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/show/1'
        assert controller.flash.message != null
        assert ${className}.count() == 1
    }

    void testShow() {
        controller.show()

        assert flash.message != null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/list'


        populateValidParams(params)
        def ${propertyName} = new ${className}(params)

        assert ${propertyName}.save() != null

        params.id = ${propertyName}.id

        def model = controller.show()

        assert model.${propertyName}Instance == ${propertyName}
    }

    void testEdit() {
        controller.edit()

        assert flash.message != null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/list'


        populateValidParams(params)
        def ${propertyName} = new ${className}(params)

        assert ${propertyName}.save() != null

        params.id = ${propertyName}.id

        def model = controller.edit()

        assert model.${propertyName}Instance == ${propertyName}
    }

    void testUpdate() {
        controller.update()

        assert flash.message != null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/list'

        response.reset()


        populateValidParams(params)
        def ${propertyName} = new ${className}(params)

        assert ${propertyName}.save() != null

        // test invalid parameters in update
        params.id = ${propertyName}.id
        //TODO: add invalid values to params object

        controller.update()

        assert view == "/${propertyName}/edit"
        assert model.${propertyName}Instance != null

        ${propertyName}.clearErrors()

        populateValidParams(params)
        controller.update()

        assert response.redirectedUrl == "/${propertyName}/show/\$${propertyName}.id"
        assert flash.message != null

        //test outdated version number
        response.reset()
        ${propertyName}.clearErrors()

        populateValidParams(params)
        params.id = ${propertyName}.id
        params.version = -1
        controller.update()

        assert view == "/${propertyName}/edit"
        assert model.${propertyName}Instance != null
        assert model.${propertyName}Instance.errors.getFieldError('version')
        assert flash.message != null
    }

    void testDelete() {
        controller.delete()
        assert flash.message != null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/list'

        response.reset()

        populateValidParams(params)
        def ${propertyName} = new ${className}(params)

        assert ${propertyName}.save() != null
        assert ${className}.count() == 1

        params.id = ${propertyName}.id

        controller.delete()

        assert ${className}.count() == 0
        assert ${className}.get(${propertyName}.id) == null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/${propertyName}/list'
    }
}`
```

So I copied it to the appropriate controller test and changed all the ${propertyName} and ${className} as such. testIndex() testList() and testCreate() passed, but testSave(), testUpdate(), testDelete() and testEdit() failed. I suppose that I need to fill in this part:

```
def populateValidParams(params) {
      assert params != null
      // TODO: Populate valid properties like...
      //params["name"] = 'someValidName'
    }
```

So I did and the method looks like this:

```
def populateValidParams(params) {
  assert params != null
  // TODO: Populate valid properties like...
  //params["name"] = 'someValidName'

  params["company"] = 'someCompany'
  params["position"] = 'somePosition'
  params["responsibilities"] = 'someResponsibility'
  params["startDate"] = new Date ('2007/01/01')
  params["endDate"] = new Date ('2010/01/01')

}
```

but still the test fails.. Am I doing something wrong? I think I'm doing it wrong with the params.. I'm a bit unfamiliar with that kind of groovy type..
This is the stacktrace for save

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Assertion failed: 

assert response.redirectedUrl == '/employmentHistory/show/1'
       |        |             |
       |        null          false
       org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletResponse@737611

    at com.someapp.controller.EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.testSave(EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.groovy:63)
```

for show:

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Assertion failed: 

assert employmentHistory.save() != null
       |                 |      |
       |                 null   false
       com.someapp.domain.EmploymentHistory : null

    at com.someapp.controller.EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.testShow(EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.groovy:78)
```

for edit:

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Assertion failed: 

assert employmentHistory.save() != null
       |                 |      |
       |                 null   false
       com.someapp.domain.EmploymentHistory : null

    at com.someapp.controller.EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.testEdit(EmploymentHistoryControllerTests.groovy:97)
```

Comment: You said 

"> So I copied it to the appropriate controller test and changed all the ${propertyName} and ${className} as such."

Grails will use those templates to generate your controller, tests, domains and etc when you use internal grails commands. You dont need to replace them manually. you can just say create-unit-test or create-integration-test and the name of your class

Answer (score 1):

The failure of `assert employmentHistory.save() != null` indicates that your `EmploymentHistory` domain object isn't validating. Make sure your params meet all of the constraints you have declared for `EmploymentHistory`.